# Find files that changed specifically in a branch

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a git repository in which I usually work on two branches, a `public` branch, and a `private` branch, the latter following closely the public branch, but with a few extra additions.

Is there a way to find the changes since a given commit that are specific to the private branch ?

The closest I can think of is to do something on the lines of:

```
git diff base..public > pub.diff
git diff base..private > private.diff
interdiff pub.diff private.diff
```

This works, but it's not that robust, and I'm sure it's possible to do that with `git` in a better way.

This is essentially how the branches look (with many more merges):

```
...A---B---C---D---E---F---G---H public
    \           \           \
     A'--I---J---D'--K---L---G'--M private
```

For instance, let's assume that `base` above is `D` in this scheme. Just running

```
git diff D'..M
```

will also give me the results of the merge commit `G'`. I'd like to avoid that, and have something robust across any numbers of merges.

Comment: `git diff public...private`?

Comment: This shows all the differences. I want to restrict that to the differences after a given commit. @RyanO'Hara

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include three dots. (It’s still probably not what you’re looking for, but at least in a different way!)

Comment: I'm unsure what the third dot does -- it does not change anything in my case @RyanO'Hara

Comment: @VincentFourmond : how does `private` follow `public` ? do you reguarly merge `public` into `private` ? do you rebase `private`on top of `public` ? something else ?

Comment: I've clarified the structure in the question @LeGEC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

> is about comparing two endpoints, not ranges

This might not be possible (`git diff` will not detect were those changes came from).

You could try using

---

#### Option A

```
$ git log -p --no-merges --first-parent D'..M
```

- `-p` gives you a diff (patch) for the commits listed
- `--no-merges` will exclude merges from the list
- `--first-parent` will only follow the first parent (the one you merged into e.g. `private`)
- `D'..M` as explained in [git revisision](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) will

  > Include commits that are reachable from `<rev2>` but exclude those that are reachable from `<rev1>`

---

#### Option B

A different approach would be to follow **@torek's** suggestion and create a temporary branch, `cherry-pick` all the commits onto it and then look at the diffs from this branch.

Because AFAIK `git cherry-pick` is not able to skip commits when specifying commit ranges you would first need to get a **list of commits** for cherry-picking (Here **Option A** is useful)

```
$ git log --no-merges --first-parent D'..M --pretty=format:%H
```

- `--pretty=format:%H` will print all the commit hashes in long form

Create the temporal branch (which needs to have the correct starting point)

```
$ git checkout -b temp D'
```

And then cherry-pick those commits manually **or** try using this command *(exchanged for a better command suggested by @torek)*

```
$ git cherry-pick $(git rev-list --reverse --topo-order --no-merges --first-parent D'..M)
```

- `--reverse` is used to reverse the order of commits printed (oldest to newest instead of the other way around)
- `--topo-order` this will avoid problems with commits that have weird or wrong timestamps
- `--no-merges` skip **merge** commits
- `--first-parent` follow the *mainline* branch (e.g. the branch the merges were merged **into**)

*This approach might fail if commits are based on changes which were merged in*

Comment: This is nice, although I don't get the diff, just a series of patches. Maybe, as you point, what I want just isn't possible ?

Comment: Indeed, it's *not* possible without copying all the commits of interest (i.e., start from `D'` and build a new chain of commits by copying `K`, `L`, and `M` while excluding merge commit `G'`). This fits in with Git's philosophy, as it were: you are not supposed to *have* to care about intermediate commits, only about the final state. To the extent that you do care (e.g., during bisect) you *do* care to follow "both sides" of merges since they affect the final state.

Comment: @torek I added an **Option B** which is based on your idea.
Vincent: Other than these two options I think there is currently no other/better way (but would like to be proven wrong)

Comment: For a slight improvement, you can `git cherry-pick $(git rev-list --reverse --topo-order --no-merges --first-parent D'..M)`.  The temporary branch can, if you like, be the anonymous branch you get with a detached HEAD; when you're done you can diff `D'` against `HEAD`.

Comment: I think this is the way to go. What I'm asking anyway becomes tricky if code that is merged in gets modified. Git is just amazingly powerful.

Comment: @torek I agree that `rev-list` is better for the job and will edit the answer as soon as I am at a keyboard. But with `--first-parent` in which cases has `--topo-order` any influence on the result?

Comment: The `--topo-order` makes sure that Git won't mis-sort commits due to weird (out of order) date stamps on them.  I am pretty sure it's not needed in *some* versions of Git, and *is* needed in other ones, but not sure which ones are which.